# Firefox keeps crashing on Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: 18.04, firefox

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 and my Firefox keeps on crashing.

I have tried the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

But nothing happen and  Firefox is still crashing.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Use some other commands, maybe they help ;-)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`. Also, log into another user account (create one if you don't already have one) and see if Firefox crashes there. That'll help tell us where the problem is. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: start in the command line with 
    firefox -p
and select a new profile. Maybe one of you addons fails. If it  crashes, display the error output

Comment: i dont have any add-ons i have reinstalled ubuntu thinking that this could be an installation error but no use my firefox is still crashing

Comment: @heynnema  total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Apr 15 23:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root     4096 Apr 15 22:49 ..

Comment: @RakiPandaga Did Firefox crash when logged into another account?

Comment: @heynnema actually firefox browser is not crashing but the tabs are crashing,i wil do that and reply to you..please give me some time

Comment: yes the firefox crashed in another user account and the system also started hanging..unfortunately had to reinstall ubuntu